# How to get href from HTML class?

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get `href` from `a = soup.find_all('div', class_='email-messages')`.

```
[<div class="email-messages">
<table>
<tr>
<td id="email-title">Message Title</td>
<td id="email-sender">Sender</td>
<td id="email-control">Control </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1">Fwd: [Microsoft Academic Verification] Confirming Your Academic Status</a></td>
<td id="email-sender"><span data-cf-modified-c9b86b506f187bfdc48368eb-="" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; show_sender_email(this, 'guidetuanhp@gmail.com')" style="cursor: pointer;">Tuấn Anh Vũ</span></td>
<td id="email-control"><a data-cf-modified-c9b86b506f187bfdc48368eb-="" href="/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1/delete" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; return delete_mail('/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1/delete');">[Delete]</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="mail_message_counter" colspan="3">Total Messages: <strong>1</strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>]
```

My code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all('div', class_='email-messages')
for link in a:
    print(link['href'])
```

I got error:

```
in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get "href" from the `<div>` tag. Try to find all `<a>` tags inside the `<div>`s:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="email-messages">
<table>
<tr>
<td id="email-title">Message Title</td>
<td id="email-sender">Sender</td>
<td id="email-control">Control </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1">Fwd: [Microsoft Academic Verification] Confirming Your Academic Status</a></td>
<td id="email-sender"><span data-cf-modified-c9b86b506f187bfdc48368eb-="" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; show_sender_email(this, 'guidetuanhp@gmail.com')" style="cursor: pointer;">Tuấn Anh Vũ</span></td>
<td id="email-control"><a data-cf-modified-c9b86b506f187bfdc48368eb-="" href="/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1/delete" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; return delete_mail('/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1/delete');">[Delete]</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="mail_message_counter" colspan="3">Total Messages: <strong>1</strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")


divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="email-messages")
for div in divs:
    for link in div.find_all("a"):
        print(link["href"])
```

Prints:

```
/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1
/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1/delete
```

Answer (score 2):

For "single-purpose" scraping it is quite useful to make use of parser customization, `SoupStrainer`. It is faster (or it should be!) since it **localize** only the desired portion of the document to be scraped. Details [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#advanced-parser-customization).

The `SoupStrainer` instance must always passed as key-value pair of a `BeautifulSoup` instance with key `parse_only`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

html_doc = # see above

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True))
for tag in soup:
    print(tag['href'])
```

Output

```
/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1
/en/msg/3EEB344D-505C-8CE7-09C5-2DD54F1AECD1/delete
```

**Remember**

1. the soup is "strained" and you will deal with a `soup`object and not with a list. So the loop variable is a `bs4.element.Tag`object!
2. `SoupStrainer` has the same signature of the `find_all` method